# how to let NumberInputCell accept the form "X.X"?

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

In GXT 3 the NumberInputCell does not accept the "X.X" form , it only accept the "X,X" form, so How can I let NumberInputCell accept the form "X.X"?

Thank you.

Comment: can you add exact code?

Comment: Thank you , i resolved the problem. I used the setDecimalSeparator method.